# Can't use WebBrowser Scrollbar on winforms

Tags: winforms, .net-4.0, webbrowser-control

I have a Winforms VB.NET application that uses a `WebBrowser` control to render HTML.

The `WebBrowser` is embedded into a `Panel`, which is on another `Panel`. So the embedding is Form --> `Panel` --> `Panel` --> `WebBrowser`

Whenever the `DocumentText` surpasses the visible borders of the `WebBrowser` the scrollbar is displayed and you'd think you can scroll with it, but you can't. The scrollbar does not respond to the mouse input. I debugged for hours now and can't find a solution. Another thing that is off, is that this is the only control where visual styles seem to be deactivated. The scrollbar looks different than other scrollbars on the **same** panel.

In summary:

1. Only control that seems to have visual styles disabled
2. Can't use scrollbar, even though it is not greyed out and actually displays a bar.

I've already created a sample project with this setup, which does not show the same problem. What could be happening here?

[image: Unnormal Scrollbar behaviour in WebBrowser]

Comment: Does the scroll bar work for any of these methods, and if so which? 1: `Mouse scroll wheel` 2: `Keyboard up and down` 3: `Keyboard Home and End` 4: `Grab bar with mouse click and drag`

Comment: Can you also confirm if you're clicking into the `WebBrowser` to ensure it has focus? If not, please try that too and report if it makes a difference. I ask because I suspect the `Panel` is swallowing some of your Win32 messages.

Comment: @Octopoid I suspect something in that ballpark, too. Altough it makes no sense, that the scrollbar inside the `TextBox` works, which also just lies on the panel. Anyways: None of the methods work.

Comment: Ah.. I was kind of hoping grabbing it would do. OK, can you try letting the WebBrowser grow to whatever height it needs to, and enabling the scrollbar on the panel instead? That might just sidestep the issue.

Comment: @Octopoid Unfortunately that is not an option. I now suspect the `WebBrowser` never receives focus and therefor it is not able to scroll. Or course this doesn't explain the strange looking scrollbar .

Comment: I'd imagine if it was a focus only issue, you'd be able to grab the bar wiith the mouse cursor though. Can you reproduce the issue in a very short test program? I created the approximate structure you're using, and scrolling worked without issue, so I'm thinking it must be something to do with the way the controls are being set up.

Comment: (WebBrowser has traditionally been known to show strange older UI chrome and the like because of the way it work. It's worth bearing in mind it's not 100% guaranteed that it will show up exactly the same on other peoples computers either.)

Comment: This is all pretty normal, you are seeing the browser's scrollbar, it always used a custom style.  You'd have to undock it and give it a big Size to see the panel's scrollbar.  Plenty of reason for the browser to be unresponsive, it burning 100% core on the javascript in the web page is a typical mishap.

Comment: @Hans Passant: 1. No JavaScript on the site. 2. If I rebuild the scenario in an example project the scrollbar looks like the one above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I guess I had a pretty unique situation here.

In my code, the `WebBrowser` was casted to a `Control` and then set to `Enabled = False`, which works for a `Control`, but is not supported for the `WebBrowser`. Afterwards the `WebBrowser` was set to `Enabled = True`. So internally, the `WebBrowser` was not selectable, because `Enabled` was `False` even though this is unsupported by the `WebBrowser`.

```
Dim xBrowser As WebBrowser
Dim xControl = CType(xBrowser, Control)
xControl.Enabled = False 'Works
xBrowser.Enabled = True 'Does not work.
'Result: WebBrowser not selectable.
```